# Getting Bios information for CPU C-State from American Megatrends

Tags: 12.04, bios

I need check wether CPU C State report is enabled or disabled in the BIOS for an American Megatrends BIOS (PPM Configuration --> CPU state report).
I can't get this information through either **biosdecode** or **dmidecode**.
(as far as I can see).
Is there any other way?
(no GUI, only terminal)
Ubuntu Server 12.04.
Best regards
Niclas